# Returning reference to object

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement linked lists that is being sorted while inserting nodes.

I have defined two structs one for Node and one that holds head and tail of list

```
struct Node{
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int value;   
};

struct List{   
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;   
};
```

I have defined function , that will insert node as the head and tail (if list is empty)

```
void insertFirst(Node *&head,Node *&tail, int value ){
        Node *tmp = new Node;
        tmp -> prev = nullptr;
        tmp -> next = nullptr;
        tmp -> value = value;
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
};
```

then i defined function that finds an (index - 1 ) where it should be placed.
So it returns element before the index where the node will be placed.

```
Node &findIndex(Node *tail ,int value){

    while(1){
        if( tail -> value > value){
            if( tail -> prev != nullptr)
                tail = tail -> prev;
            else
                return *tail;
        }else{
            return *tail;
        }
    }

}
```

and function that insert element at its place

```
void InsertAfter(Node *&x,int value){

    Node *tmp           = new Node;
    tmp -> value        = value;
    tmp -> next         = x -> next;
    tmp -> prev         = x;
    x -> next -> prev   = tmp;
    x   -> next         = tmp;

}
```

I all invoke it onefunction

```
void InsertNode(Node *&head, Node *&tail , int value){
    if( head == nullptr){
        insertFirst(head,tail,value);
    }else{   
        InsertAfter(findIndex(tail,value),value);
    }    
}
```

and ofc main

```
List list;
    InsertNode(list.head,list.tail,5);
    InsertNode(list.head,list.tail,5);
    InsertNode(list.head,list.tail,5);
    Node *x = list.head;
    while(x!=nullptr){
        cout << x-> value << endl;
        x = x->next;
    }
```

But i keep getting error

> invalid initialization of reference of type 'Node*&' from expression
>   of type 'Node'|

What does it mean? The return type of fintIndex is refference to a pointer , as is the argument of insertNode function.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look closer at the code.
First, tweak `findIndex()`:

```
Node * findIndex(Node *tail ,int value) {      // pass tail by value

      // traverse to find the right index as it does

    return tail;  // return what tail points to
}
```

`findIndex()` will return what tail is pointing to *i.e* some `Node`. `InsertAfter()` will have a `Node` as an argument instead of *pointer to the Node*. Here, `Node` is passed by reference.

```
void InsertAfter(Node *x, int value) {

    // the same

}
```

I hope this helps. Sorry, I couldn't find the solution by *returning pointer to a Node* from `findIndex()`. I'm following the question and hoping someone gets the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

FindIndex returns a reference to Node, but InsertAfter takes a reference to a pointer to Node.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> invalid initialization of reference of type 'Node*&' from expression of type 'Node'|

means that somewhere in your code you are assigning variable of type `Node` to variable of type `Node*&`, example:

```
struct Node{};

Node node;    

foo(node);  // this is wrong and produces
            // error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Node*&' from expression of type 'Node'

Node* pnode = &node;
foo(pnode);  // this is ok!
```

[edit]

After second time look at you code, I suggest making all you parameters references to pointer: `*&` see fixed code below. This works for your test scenerio, I am not sure if it wont fail under other cases:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45b3589d716da18a

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int value;
};

struct List{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;
};

void insertFirst(Node *&head,Node *&tail, int value ){
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp -> prev = nullptr;
    tmp -> next = nullptr;
    tmp -> value = value;
    head = tmp;
    tail = tmp;
}

Node*& findIndex(Node*& tail ,int value){

    while(1){
        if( tail -> value > value){
            if( tail -> prev != nullptr)
                tail = tail -> prev;
            else
                return tail;
        }else{
            return tail;
        }
    }

}

void InsertAfter(Node *&x,int value){

    Node *tmp           = new Node;
    tmp -> value        = value;
    tmp -> next         = x -> next;
    tmp -> prev         = x;

    // SO !!! - below two line order was changed
    x->next = tmp;
    x->next->prev = tmp;
}

void InsertNode(Node *&head, Node *&tail , int value){
    if( head == nullptr){
        insertFirst(head,tail,value);
    }else{
        InsertAfter(findIndex(tail,value),value);
    }
}

int main()
{
    List list;
    InsertNode(list.head,list.tail,5);
    InsertNode(list.head,list.tail,5);
    InsertNode(list.head,list.tail,5);
    Node *x = list.head;
    while(x!=nullptr){
        cout << x-> value << endl;
        x = x->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its propably in the  InsertAfter() function , but it takes pointer to reference , and it also recieves it , so did i overlook something? I cant see the problem there. But seems like it is a problem

Comment: it throws almost same  error invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Node*&' from an rvalue of type 'Node*'|

Comment: @trolkura I have looked closer at your code, and added edit to my answer, look at it - it should solve it.

Comment: Is the code returning the `tail` that will be no longer there?

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD you are right, this would be probably UB. I dont really see any use of those references to pointer. @trolkura you should replace all the occurences of `*&` with `*`. For example inside `InsertAfter` you are not assigning to `x` but only dereferencing it, so what is the use of reference here?

Comment: I think he wants to generalize `InsertAfter()` by being able to accept to both pure pointer and the return-value from `findIndex()`

Comment: @trolkura see my fixes to your code in my edited answer, NERDYLIZARD - not I think the best aproach is to change everywhere in parameters to *&